# Quick Sum TopCoder (Brute Force solution)

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> Given a string of digits, find the minimum number of additions
>   required for the string to equal some target number. Each addition is
>   the equivalent of inserting a plus sign somewhere into the string of
>   digits. After all plus signs are inserted, evaluate the sum as usual.
>   For example, consider the string "12" (quotes for clarity). With zero
>   additions, we can achieve the number 12. If we insert one plus sign
>   into the string, we get "1+2", which evaluates to 3. So, in that case,
>   given "12", a minimum of 1 addition is required to get the number 3.
>   As another example, consider "303" and a target sum of 6. The best
>   strategy is not "3+0+3", but "3+03". You can do this because leading
>   zeros do not change the result.
>
> Write a class QuickSums that contains the method minSums, which takes
>   a String numbers and an int sum. The method should calculate and
>   return the minimum number of additions required to create an
>   expression from numbers that evaluates to sum. If this is impossible,
>   return -1.
>
> <sub>[TopCoder link](https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=2829&rd=5072)</sub>

So I came up with a brute force solution of checking all possible solutions to find the min. Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class QuickSums {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "99999";
    int total = 45;
    int res = minSums(input, total);
    System.out.println(res);
  }

  // With at most 10 digits(constraint given), there are at most 2^9 ways to insert plus signs into the string.
  // Therefore, there are at most 2^9 possibilities to consider. We can use recursion to go through
  // all possibilities and keep track of the minimum number of additions required
  public static int minSums(String numbers, int sum) {
    int N = numbers.length();

    // base cases
    if (N <= 3 && sum == Integer.parseInt(numbers)) {
      return 0;
    }

    else if (N == 2 && Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(0, N - 1))
        + Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(N - 1)) == sum) {
      return 1;
    } else if (N == 2 && Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(0, N - 1))
        + Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(N - 1)) != sum) {
      return -1;
    }
    else if (N == 1 && Integer.parseInt(numbers) != sum) {
      return -1;
    }

    // solution
    else {

      int lenOFStr = N-1;
      int possibleCombination = (int) Math.pow(2, lenOFStr);

      // numbers will contain between 1 and 10 characters, inclusive.
      int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      StringBuilder tempString;
      for (int i = 0; i < possibleCombination; i++) {
        String plus = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        while (plus.length() < lenOFStr) {
          plus = "0" + plus;
        }
        // System.out.println(plus);

        // Add plus sign to the string
        tempString = new StringBuilder(numbers);
        int len = N;
        for (int k = 0; k < lenOFStr ; k++) {
          if (plus.charAt(k) == '1') {
            len = len + 1;
            int offset = len-N+k;
           // System.out.println(offset);
            tempString.insert(offset, " ");
          }
        }
        // System.out.println(tempString);

        // compute the sum
        String[] arr = tempString.toString().split(" ");
        long tempSum = 0;
        for (String s : arr) {
          tempSum +=Long.parseLong(s);
        }

        // check if the sum is same
        if (tempSum == sum) {
          min = Math.min(arr.length-1, min);
        }


      }
      return (min == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : min;

    }
  }

}
```

This program works fine for all inputs but I'm wondering, there must be a *dynamic programming* solution to this? Or something better?

Comment: "You can do this because leading zeros do not change the result." <- does this mean leading zeroes can effectively be trimmed away?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> public static int minSums(String numbers, int sum) {
>   int N = numbers.length();
> ```

variables should be named using `camelCase` casing so `n` would be better, but what does `N/n` represent ? Its the number of digits contained in the `String numbers` which isn't named correctly because there is only one number passed which consists of multiple digits. So a better way would be like so

```
public static int minSums(String number, int sum) {
  int digits = number.length();
```

but as the default indentation is `4` spaces this should be like so

```
public static int minSums(String number, int sum) {
    int digits = number.length();
```

---

This `if..else if..else` construct can be simplified because for the first cases you are returning a value the `else if..else` aren't needed and will save some horizontal spacing if removed. You should have the two cases where you check for `N == 2` into one single `if` with a nested `if..else` like so

```
// changed N to digits

if (digits <= 3 && sum == Integer.parseInt(numbers)) {
    return 0;
}

if (digits == 2) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(0, N - 1))
       + Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(N - 1)) == sum) {
        return 1;      
    } else {
        return -1;      
    }
}

if (digits == 1 && Integer.parseInt(numbers) != sum) {
  return -1;
}

// solution
```

---

Commented out code is dead code and should be removed because it is only adding noise to the code which decreases readability.

---

Let your variables and operators have some space to breathe. Something like `int offset = len-N+k;` isn't just as readable as `int offset = len -N + k;`.

---

Answer (score 2):

For what I see, there are a couple of things that should be improved.

---

As @Heslacher mentioned in his answer, naming should be changed into something better. I'd suggest to change:

```
public static int minSums(String numbers, int sum) {
    int N = numbers.length();
```

into something like:

```
public static int minSums(String digits, int sum) {
    int numberOfDigits = digits.length();
```

---

The current method `minSums` does a bit too much IMO. It parses the string and also finds the solutions. I'd split that in two parts: one which gets all the possible numbers starting from the original string and one which finds the solution based on the numbers taken from the additional method.

---

As an alternative solution, I'd suggest the following (in pseudo-code):

```
// this method should return all possible numbers in a string
// of digits. For "1234" it should return {1,2,3,4,12,23,34,123,234}
int[] getPossibleNumbers(String digits){
    char[] chars = digits.toCharArray();
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    int helper;
    int zero = 48; // this is the char val for the '0' digit

    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < chars.length && (i + j) < chars.length; j++){
            helper = 0;

            for(int k = 0; k < j; k++){
                helper = (helper * 10) + ((int)chars[i + k]) - zero;
            }

            numbers.append(helper);
        }
    }

    return numbers.toArray();
}

int minSums(String digits, int sum){
    int[] numbers = getPossibleNumbers(digits);
    Queue<SumStatus> backupQueue = new Queue<SumStatus>();
    int numbersStartingIndex; // this index will be used to get the various numbers to sum

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        SumStatus status = new SumStatus(new List<int>().append(numbers[i]), numbers[i]);
        backupQueue.push(status);
    }

    while(!backupQueue.isEmpty()){
        SumStatus status = backupQueue.pop();

        if(status.sum == sum){
            // we found the min-sum
            return status.numbers.length() - 1;
        }

        if(status.sum < sum){
            // we have not found the min-sum yet

            if(status.availableNumbers.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < status.availableNumbers.length; i++){
                    SumStatus newStatus = new SumStatus(status.numbers, status.sum);
                    newStatus.numbers.append(status.availableNumbers[i]);
                    newStatus.sum += status.availableNumbers[i];
                    // copy the new available numbers (all the previously available ones except for the one in position 'i')
                    newStatus.availableNumbers = CopyArray(status.availableNumbers, exceptIndex: i);

                    if(newStatus.sum <= sum){
                        backupQueue.push(status);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // when status.sum > sum the item is simply ignored and popped from the queue
    }

    // no possible combination found
    return -1;
}

class SumStatus{
    List<int> numbers;
    int[] availableNumbers;
    int sum;

    SumStatus(List<int> nums, int currentSum){
        numbers = nums;
        sum = currentSum;
    }
}
```

The proposed solution does a [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) in the [State Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_space) of the problem. The State Space is made of: the numbers evaluated up to that state, the sum of the used numbers, and the available numbers (the ones not yet used). The Breadth-First Search may not be immediatly visible because there's no tree to visit in a recursive fashion, but it's implemented via a `Queue<SumStatus>`.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

P.S.: The code is not working code. It just serves as a means to clarify the idea I had.